# Python Scraping from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've tried to write a web scraper for https://www.waug.com/area/?idx=15:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#_*_coding:utf8_*_

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.abcd.com/area/?abc=15')

html = url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

count = 1

names = soup.select('#good_{} > div > div.class_name > div > div'.format(count))
prices = soup.select('#good_{} > div > div.class_name > div.class_name'.format(count))

for name in names:
    while count < 45:
        print(name.text)
        count = count + 1

for price in prices:
    while count < 45:
        print(price.text)
        count = count + 1
```

The output is only 45 times first item name and no price. How can I get all item name and price? I want to get item name and price on same line. (I've changed the url and some of the class names just in case)

Comment: It is hard to help you without the real website name / url.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you only want the first 45 items, then why not use `list(zip(names, prices))[:45]`?

Comment: @BaileyParker I'd like to get all item name and price. more than 40 items in there.

Comment: @Pitto here's the website url waug.com/area/?idx=15

Comment: What does "more than 40 items in there" mean? What are you trying to accomplish with all of the 45s? If you use zip you can get the names and prices together in tuples.

Comment: @BaileyParker I am sorry I'm not fluent in English. Pitto can help me i think. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be sure to get the right name for the right title I'd get the whole "item-good" class.

Then using a for loop would allow me to be sure that the title I am getting matches its price.

Here's an example of how to parse a website with BeautifulSoup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#_*_coding:utf8_*_

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.waug.com/area/?idx=15')

html = url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

count = 1

items = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-good"})

for item in items:
  item_title = item.find("div", {"class": "good-title-text"})
  item_price = item.find("div", {"class": "price-selling"})
  print item_title.text + " "  + item_price.text
  # If you get encoding errors delete the row above and uncomment the one below
  #print item_title.text.encode("utf-8") + " "  + item_price.text.encode("utf-8")
```

As per OP's request this is not enough because there is a "more" button to push in the webpage in order to retrieve all the results.

This can be done using Selenium Webdriver.

=== IMPORTANT NOTE ===

In order to make this work you'll need to copy in your script folder also the "chromedriver" file.

You can download it from [this Google website](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Here's the script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.waug.com/area/?idx=15')



for number in range(10):
    try:
       WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "more_good")))
       more_button = browser.find_element_by_id('more_good')
       more_button.click()
       time.sleep(10)
    except:
       print "Scrolling is now complete!"

source = browser.page_source

# This source variable should be used as input for BeautifulSoup
print source
```

Now it is tie to merge the two explained soultions in order to get the final requested result.

Please keep it mind that this is just a quick'n'dirty hack and needs proper error handling and polishing but it should be enough to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#_*_coding:utf8_*_

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.waug.com/area/?idx=15')

def is_page_load_complete():
    close_button = browser.find_element_by_id('close_good');
    return close_button.is_displayed();

while(True):
    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "more_good")))
    time.sleep(10)
    more_button = browser.find_element_by_id('more_good')
    if (more_button.is_displayed()):
        more_button.click()
    else:
        if (is_page_load_complete()):
            break

source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
items = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-good"})

for item in items:
  item_title = item.find("div", {"class": "good-title-text"})
  item_price = item.find("div", {"class": "price-selling"})
  print item_title.text + " "  + item_price.text
  # If you get encoding errors comment the row above and uncomment the one below
  #print item_title.text.encode("utf-8") + " "  + item_price.text.encode("utf-8")

print "Total items found: " + str(len(items))
```

Comment: Please explain why you would do it that way. Code only answers are only useful for this one specific use-case.

Comment: Explanation added, @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: It shows only 13 items. there's a "view more" button below.

Comment: True, @Blastah.
Let me analyze that, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: Mmmmh, quite tricky @Blastah!

I have a working solution using Selenium but the list is neverending...

How many times should I push the "more" button?

Comment: @Pitto 4 times. and then button changed to "close"

Comment: I am really sorry I've got to go now @Pitto. I really appreciate for your effort. at least I know how to print two things in one line. Thank you and have a good rest of the day!!